# Where is my Entity Framework 5 Generated Database?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-5

I can't find my database file anywhere. I can hit the database so I know it is there.

I used this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="TestPocoTimeEntryContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In my code, if I run this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(db.Database.Connection.Database + " Exists " + db.Database.Exists());
```

I get this output:

```
" Exists True"
```

I cannot understand why the database is there but it has no name and there is no file for it.

Let me know if I need to provide further info. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check under App_Data folder ?

Comment: I don't have an app data folder. I followed this tutorial but my situation is different because I am using VS Express and I didn't connect using server credentials (as you can see above from my connection string). Here is the tutorial link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbDOhCjjxSY